# Creating a javascript search bar for website and having trouble linking to correct page based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take the user input from the search bar, translate it into a string and then open up the webpage i have created using the input they have given me.

Here is what i am looking to do.

```
if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = 'myPages/userData.html'
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
```

When i try to add in the variable userData, which is the user input from the search bar, doing it like this:

```
if(userData){
            icon.onclick = ()=>{
                webLink = 'myPages/' + userData + '.html'
                linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
                linkTag.click();
            }
```

This comes off as an error and says it cannot find the file to redirect to.

I am new to javascript and need to figure out how to pass the variable in and create the correct address to open up the new html file page.

I have already taken out the spaces and formatting from the user input, as well as tried to create a new variable containing the address but both did not work and i still got the same error saying there are quotations in the address so it cannot be found.

Comment: When you `console.log(userData)` does it display what you are expecting?  Also `console.log('myPages/' + userData + '.html')` to see what your path looks like and try hitting that URL directly.

Comment: so what is the hierarchy of your web pages?

Comment: In addition to Zak's comment above, it would be helpful for the question to note what "cannot be found" means -- are you getting a 404? What web server are you using, or is this raw html/javascript on your file system?

Comment: @Zak I have figured it out now sorry. There was an unwanted space in my file heirarchy  which was causing the error in my browser. I was going crazy because i was sure I could pass that variable in there like that. Thanks for replying everyone sorry for the stupid mistake.